# Convert 'Task<IList<T>>' to 'IList<T>'

Tags: c#, task, ilist

This is my task method:

```
public static async Task<IList<ResourceModel>> GetResourcesByName()
```

And this is in another class where I want to use the returned values from the task method:

```
 Task<IList<ResourceModel>> imagelist = RMS.SharedMobile.Adapter.ResourceAdapter.GetResourcesByName();
```

I want to do a `foreach` loop to iterate through the list it returns, but that is not possible if it is a `Task`. So how do I convert it to a usefull `IList` or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can, use `await`

```
var imageList = await RMS.SharedMobile.Adapter.ResourceAdapter.GetResourcesByName();
```

Or:

```
var imageList = RMS.SharedMobile.Adapter.ResourceAdapter.GetResourcesByName().Result;
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the possibility of deadlocks when using `.Result()`

Comment: Prefer `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to `.Result`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
imagelist.ContinueWith((sender) =>
{
   var result = sender.result
   foreach(var item in result)
   {
     //do stuff
   }
}
```